# how to use hapi to set cookie?

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

I read the official documentation of hapi.js, the code is similar to the documentation, but it is impossible to set a cookie

```
const Hapi=require('hapi');
const server = Hapi.server({
    host:'localhost',
    port:3333
});

server.state('user', {
    ttl: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,     // One day
    isSecure: true,
    isHttpOnly: true,
    encoding: 'base64json',
    clearInvalid: false,
    strictHeader: true
});
server.route({
    method:'POST',
    path:'/login',
    handler:function(request,h) {
        var data = request.payload;

        if(data.account === "a" && data.password === "a"){
            h.state('user', { account: "shmily" });

            console.log(request.state.user); //undefined

            return h.response('success');
        }else{
            return "wrong";
        }

    }
});
async function start() {
    try {
        await server.start();
    }
    catch (err) {
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log('服务器开启了3333端口！');
};
start();
```

I want to set the cookie but it does not work.My English is not very good, I hope everyone can be more tolerant.

Comment: please provide your code here instead of posting images

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change isSecure to false in development. When it is set to true cookie is not set when there is no secure connection(https).

So change your code so it looks like this

```
server.state('user', {
   ttl: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,     // One day
   isSecure: false,
   isHttpOnly: true,
   encoding: 'base64json',
   clearInvalid: false,
  strictHeader: true
});
```